# Edit Rails Model From Command Line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, data-modeling, scaffolding

I am pretty new to Ruby on Rails, and I was wondering if there was a way to edit the database schema for a model.

For example, I have the Subscriber model in my application -- the way I created it was by using  `rails generate scaffold Subscriber email:string`

But now, I want a name in the subscriber model as well. Is there any easy way to do this? I have put a lot of code in my current controllers and views, so I don't necessarily want to destroy the scaffold, but I would like to edit the model.

Thanks in advance,

hwrd

P.S. I am using Ruby on Rails 3

Comment: Reading http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html should be very helpful.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

An ActiveRecord Model inspects the table it represents. You don't actually need to change your model just to add a new field (unless you want to add validations, etc).

What you want to do is make a new migration and then migrate your database up:

```
rails g migration AddNameToSubscribers name:string
rake db:migrate
```

Then you can start referencing the name field in your controllers and views.

(This generator command might seem a little magical, but the rails generator recognizes this format and will generate the appropriate `add_column` and `remove_column` code. See the [Rails migration guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#creating-a-standalone-migration) for further reading.)

Comment: But don't the old columns in the DB still take up space? I didn't look at it this way though. Thats a good point.

Comment: @hwrdprkns: Yes, they still take up space. I'm not sure what you're asking. This command will add the `name` field to your `subscribers` table. Is that not what you wanted?

Comment: Old columns haven't been deleted, so they will still take up space. The migration above is only adding a column to the subscribers table, that is all.

Comment: Josh, I was asking how I could edit the database schema of a model. I think a combination of you and Jesse's answers is what I wanted. In any case, I'm sure I can play around with these ideas until I can get it to work for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean changing the database schema of your model, you'll want to use migrations.

You'll do things like

```
add_column :city, :string
remove_column :boo
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

If you do only mean finding models and updating the data inside each instance, go with @apneadiving's answer.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. I mean changing the database schema -- sorry I didn't make that clear. After this command, will my schema be updated for good? Also, as just a side note -- does remove_column also bash any/all data in the column for that model?

Comment: @hwrdprkns, when a column is removed from a table, all data for that is lost. And what @Jesse Wolgamott is saying is essentially the same thing as what @Josh Lindsey said..

Comment: Sorry I voted this down, I didn't mean to! If you edit your answer I'll vote it back up!